# How split pandas value according to some rule and sum up spliting values in the same colums value

Tags: python, pandas

I have one column in `pandas` `dataframe` which has for example this kind of data,"4885.5800|4885". I want to `split` this value and replace this value, by summing up splitting values(4885.5800+4885). But all of them are not the same type, some of them have just one value.
[image]

Comment: Post an example of your dataframe, and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

This will `split` it up into string subsets with `"|"` char separating, convert `string` types to `float`, and sum it up

```
sum(map(labmda x:float(x),s.split("|"))
```